# Fixed position for boxes at the body area

Tags: spacing, boxes

*First of all, I'd like to find a solution **without Tikz (PGF)** because I'll share this file and people could not be able to install additional packages. So simplest solution could be good.*

I'd like to insert logo, author, title and date like the figure below (the dimensions used are just to exemplify, but they will be constant).

[image]

The position of title box should be always the same, even if the author box changes its height.

The red arrows indicate to where the box should expand if necessary.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[grid=false]{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}%
\vspace*{3cm}
\noindent\hfil\parbox[t]{.8\linewidth}{%
\hfil\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}%
}

% author box here

% title box here exactly at the center of body

\vfill
\noindent\hfil\parbox[b]{.8\linewidth}{%
\centering\today\\\the\year
}
\vspace*{2cm}
\end{document}
```

As you can see with the help of the grid, the date box is good I think.

[image]

But I don't know why the first vertical space `\vspace*{3cm}` is not correct. I think that some inner space related to `parbox` is affecting it.

[image]

Finally, the difficulty part is to insert the other two boxes well positioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest place to find a fixed point on the page is the page head (or foot) so you can place each of the boxes by coordinate from the baseline of the header using a zero sized picture mode. I just do 3 here, using 1cm units.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[grid=false]{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}%

\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{%
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,-3){%
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}}%
\put(0,-7){%
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\parbox{.8\textwidth}{\centering some text here\\ and here}}}%
\put(0,-12){%
\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering some text here\\ and here}}%
\end{picture}\hfill}
\makeatother
\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

If you have more pages after, use `\pagestyle{plain}` or whatever to get back to notmal.

Comment: Where is the anchor point of the `parbox`? Do we need it to compute the real distance from the header baseline? If we increase the height of the second box, will it move up or down?

Comment: Well, if I'm not wrong, the baseline of the box is the bottom line. So if the box has more lines, it will grow up instead of grow down.

Comment: @Sigur\parbox is vertically centred, \parbox[t] takes baseline of first line \parbox[b] takes baseline of bottom line, pick which you want:-)

Comment: OK, now I understand the alignment in `parbox`. The problem now is to know what is the coordinate `y` to put the box with baseline of 1st line exactly at the middle of body area. This is not the behaviour I'd like as in my figure, but it is satisfactory. Thanks for a while.